# Delphi select line in a dbgrid and show other lines in other dbgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have 2 dbgrid which are connected to two different SQL databases. One is "provider" table which coloumns are (provider_name, provider_adress), other table is customer table with (customer_name, customer_adress, provider_name). More customers can belong to one provider. The common field is the provider's name.

My question is... I want to list the customer names belongins to providers. If i click on a random 'provider_name' in a dbgrid, the customer table dbgrid will be active and will show the customer_names, adresses etc..) I use AdoDatasets and AdoQueries.

```sql
Select * from customer_name, customer_adress --(in customer table) 
where provider name = 'xy' --(in provider table)
```

Anyone can help in a query? Anyone can help me how can i do it?Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It sounds like a common master detail view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate query for your customer table, with SQL something like this (replace `CustQuery` with the name of your own ADOQuery component, and the table and column names for your actual table information, of course):

```
CustQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT c.customer_name, c.customer_address' + #13 +
                      'FROM customer c' + #13 +
                      'WHERE c.provider_name = :provider';
```

In the provider query's `AfterScroll` event handler, use code something like this (generate it from double-clicking the `AfterScroll` event in the Object Inspector Events tab):

```
procedure TForm1.ProviderQueryAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CustQuery.DisableControls;
  try
    CustQuery.Close;
    CustQuery.Paramseters.ParamByName('provider').Value :=
      ProviderQuery.FieldByname('Provider_Name').Value;
    CustQuery.Open;
  finally
    CustQuery.EnableControls;
  end;
  CustQuery.Open;
end;
```

The above will work whether the user clicks a new row in the provider grid or uses the keyboard to scroll through rows.